# Calling Bootstrap() on two root Components of the same class in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components, angular2-compiler

I have found that when *bootstrap()* is called it will match a class instance to a selector on the DOM and insert a shadow DOM.

Therefore, in order to try to get two root Components of the same class bootstrapped, I have specified a distinct *'selector'* on each.

However, while each component gets bootstrapped with a distinct 'selector', if I look at each Component's annotation metadata, they both are pointing to the same *'_hostElement.nativeElement'*.

Ex:

The following prints the annotation meta showing the *'_hostElement.nativeElement'*.

```
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppComponent));
```

for the following class declaration:

```
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentResolver) {
  console.log('annotations');
  console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppComponent));

  }
}
```

This is how I bootstrap each instance so that they have distinct selectors:

```
bootstrap( Component({
  selector: 'my-app-' + id,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  template: `<p>Dynamic Component {{message}}</p>`
 })(AppComponent)).then(app => {
    //app['_hostElement'].nativeElement =  `<div class="Ng2"><h1>Angular 2-${this.context.instanceId}</h2><my-app-${this.context.instanceId}/></div>`
    console.log(app['_hostElement'].nativeElement);
    console.log('Bootstrap Successful');
    console.log(app);
}, err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

The above bootstrap function returns a Promise, which is successful for both instances, contrary to what one would expect.

When I inspect the DOM, I can see that there are two distinct *'selector'* tags that identify the root apps as intended, but as pictured below - the bootstrapped components *'ComponentRef_'* points to the same *'_hostElement.nativeElement'*.

[Here is the 'ComponentRef_' of the bootstrap call - both call's return the same ComponentRef_[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vJt.png)

How can I get two root components of the same class to play nicely?

Comment: Why not just create a new root component and push the current root component down one level?

Comment: @JohnSiu The unexpected behavior is not incurred because of the relationship between the instantiated instances - but rather because the component class will have two 'component annotations' defined on it's metadata as a result of bootstrapping with a different selector field twice. The Bootstrap function will return a successful promise but the Component instances will both point to the first annotation metadata object that was bootstrapped with the Component. - Thus leading to an unexpected behavior. I have found a solution and will follow up with a documented code sample.